# How can I make a Python program do some task at some times of the day?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to make a Python program do some task at some times of the day (for example at 12:00, 12:30,13:00, 13:30, etc.) without using sleep(), so the program can make other tasks while it waits.

Comment: Are you sure python is the best way to do this? Also, what operationnal system are you working with?

Comment: You should probably use tools provided by your OS rather than writing it yourself in Python.  You can use things like [`Task Scheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) on Windows or [`Cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) on Linux.

Comment: I am working on windows 10. I am using python to read some data in a PLC.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.datetime.now().time()` will get the current time. Thus, create simple `if` statements that check for the time, and if they match, execute the code.

Comment: I think of that but I do not know if that would be good to be checking that all time.